# Why did Doug Forcett get points?

Tags: the-good-place

The show has multiple references that if you do good deeds while having a self-interest in mind, you won't get points.

The two biggest examples were:

- Eleanor was trying to do good things in the fake Bad Place, but wasn't getting any points. And at some point, they figured out that her motivation is all wrong because the only reason why she does it is to stay from a real Bad Place.
- And they referred several times to Tahani's life that she did a lot of charity, but the motives were wrong.

I am curious, why was it different for Doug Forcett? He got something like half a million points (which I assume is really impressive number in the modern world). However, when Michael asks him why he doesn't want to relax a bit and have some fun, Doug replies that he can't risk it. He doesn't want to go to the Bad Place.

And thinking about it, his situation is no different from Eleanor's. Both of them know about the existence of Good Place and Bad Place. Both of them try to do good things to avoid Bad Place. However, Doug somehow was able to accumulate points.

Comment: The answer might be a possible spoiler. How far are you in the series?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117279/why-could-doug-forcett-earn-points

Comment: TL:DR He didn't really knew it, he "only" believed.

Comment: @tilley31 I watched all of it.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's the reason. He took a guess and turned out he was "92% correct". Eleanor knew for a fact. And also, remember that (spoiler for the end of season 1) it was Eleanor's personal he*l (bad place) specifically designed for her, so it didn't matter anyway...

Comment: @Mithoron. I just realized that it only answers half of the question. It makes total sense when you compare it to Eleanor. Eleanor knew, and Doug just guessed. However, it doesn't answer the question about Tahani. Tahani (when we were alive) didn't know, and she was acting in a self-serving way, pretty much the same way as Doug was doing.

Comment: Maybe his "motivation was flawed!" in the beginning, but probably it became his nature to act as he did. Either that or it's a plot hole ;)